# Generating YouTube Custom PlayList issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I want to build a custom youtube playlist from [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-bluemix-youtube/index.html) using the YouTube API and I got stuck at a certain point.
I basically embedded the client.js script and execute it's function on loading and after that i embedded also the YouTubePlayList.js file as stated in the tutorial. 
Here is a fiddle of what i'm trying to do. I do receive the YouTubePlayList object in console but it doesn't seem to give any proper data. I need a working script example or guidance on how to achieve it to work and have the playlist rendered in my client. Thanks in advance, any help appreciated!

JS:

```
<pre>

function YouTubePlayList (id, entries) {
    this.id = id; 
    this.entries = entries; 
    this.currently_playing = 0; 
    this.randomizer = false; 
}
var requestOptions = {
    playlistId: 'PLLzJfby7cTLTbusOgXca-yIpVOImC1mWe',
    part: 'contentDetails, snippet',
    execute: function(response) {
        var entries = [];
        $.each(response.items, function(key, val){
            var entry = {};
            entry.video_id = val.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            entry.image_src = val.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            entry.title = val.snippet.title;
            entry.note = val.contentDetails.note;
            entries.push(entry);
        });
    }
};
window['PLLzJfby7cTLTbusOgXca-yIpVOImC1mWe'] = new YouTubePlayList('PLLzJfby7cTLTbusOgXca-yIpVOImC1mWe', 1);
console.log(window['PLLzJfby7cTLTbusOgXca-yIpVOImC1mWe']);

</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit [Playlists: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists)

This will help you create a new playlist in your channel. The page is jam packed of ideas that will help you to start. There are also example such as the .js code below.

```
// Define some variables used to remember state.
var playlistId, channelId;

// After the API loads, call a function to enable the playlist creation form.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  enableForm();
}

// Enable the form for creating a playlist.
function enableForm() {
  $('#playlist-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Create a private playlist.
function createPlaylist() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
    part: 'snippet,status',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'Test Playlist',
        description: 'A private playlist created with the YouTube API'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    var result = response.result;
    if (result) {
      playlistId = result.id;
      $('#playlist-id').val(playlistId);
      $('#playlist-title').html(result.snippet.title);
      $('#playlist-description').html(result.snippet.description);
    } else {
      $('#status').html('Could not create playlist');
    }
  });
}

// Add a video ID specified in the form to the playlist.
function addVideoToPlaylist() {
  addToPlaylist($('#video-id').val());
}

// Add a video to a playlist. The "startPos" and "endPos" values let you
// start and stop the video at specific times when the video is played as
// part of the playlist. However, these values are not set in this example.
function addToPlaylist(id, startPos, endPos) {
  var details = {
    videoId: id,
    kind: 'youtube#video'
  }
  if (startPos != undefined) {
    details['startAt'] = startPos;
  }
  if (endPos != undefined) {
    details['endAt'] = endPos;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
    part: 'snippet',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: details
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    $('#status').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

Try to explore [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_playlist_information).

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your
>   website and control the player using JavaScript.
>
> Using the API's JavaScript functions, you can queue videos for
>   playback; play, pause, or stop those videos; adjust the player volume;
>   or retrieve information about the video being played. You can also add
>   event listeners that will execute in response to certain player
>   events, such as a player state change or a video playback quality
>   change.
>
> This guide explains how to use the IFrame API. It identifies the
>   different types of events that the API can send and explains how to
>   write event listeners to respond to those events. It also details the
>   different JavaScript functions that you can call to control the video
>   player as well as the player parameters you can use to further
>   customize the player.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it really helped me out another great video resource that I've found is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdqsiFw74Jk) ... in here you also get the idea on what requests you actuall need to send, how to send them, and how to get the data object that's needed to embed afterwards in your personal web page